# Ruby, Webrick think every local port is already in use

Tags: ruby, localhost, webrick

I am developing a static site locally. To view it in a browser, I run this command

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
```

to run a local webserver at localhost:8000.

Starting yesterday, when I run it, I get the error

```
INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-12-16) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1158 port=8000
```

So I change the port number `-p8000` to `p8001` and I get the same error. I try 8002, 8003, 8888, 1313, 8004. I the same error on **every single port number**. Ruby, or Webrick, thinks that every port is already in use.

All the solutions to this problem I can find online suggest finding whatever process is hogging the port using commands like `lsof | grep '8000'` or `lsof -wni tcp:8000` and then killing that process. But those commands don't return anything. There are no processes using those ports.

This happens on a fresh restart of my machine. Wifi turned off.